# How to get a “nice” URL that can be bookmarked in Flask-WTF?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I try to learn Flask and I can't find an answer to the question: Is there a way to get a “clean” URL, that can be bookmarked, if I use GET as form method with the Flask-WTF plugin?

If I use in a template the method POST:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
```

The URL in the browser will not alter, in Flask's debug mode it would be:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

If I submit the form.

If I use the method GET, the URL would look like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/?name=test&submit=Submit&csrf_token=1453393786%23%23a327427d
```

But I would like to use the Flask-WTF plugin to make forms and get back a nice, bookmarkable URL in the browser like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/?name=test
```

Is that possible?

What I try to achieve is something like this in PHP:

```
<?php
   if( $_GET["name"] ) {
        echo "Hello, ". $_GET['name']. "!";
        exit();
    }
?>
<html>
   <body>

      <form action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method = "GET">
         Name: <input type = "text" name = "name" />
         <input type = "submit" />
      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

After submitting, I get this URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1/test.php?name=test
```

I can copy this link, send it to someone else, he or she can open it with a browser and will get the same result. It is simply done, by using the method GET in the form. Look at this:

```
http://www.utrace.de/?query=8.8.8.8
```

With Flask I cloud do this:

```
http://127.0.0.1/query/8.8.8.8
```

But what, if I would use more than one parameter? In PHP it would look like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1/?para1=8.8.8.8&para2=US
```

I've tried it, using this code (lent from Miguel Grinberg):

Program:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import Required, Length

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'top secret!'

class NameForm(Form):
    name = StringField('What is your name?', validators=[Required(),
                                                         Length(1, 16)])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    name = None
    form = NameForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        name = form.name.data
        form.name.data = ''
    return render_template('index.html', form=form, name=name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Template:

```
<form method="GET" action="">
    {{ form.name.label }} {{ form.name(size=16) }}
    {% for error in form.name.errors %}
        {{ error }}
    {% endfor %}
     <br>
    {{ form.submit() }}
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
</form>
    {% if name %}
        <h1>Hello, {{ name }}!</h1>
    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest factoring this out into its own view. You should use CSRF for forms, and you should try to separate GET and POST interfaces.

Forcing one piece of code or function to do multiple things sometimes might seem cleaner, but what happens is you add to maintainability costs and make things less clear down the road.

How you'd do this in Flask:

```
@app.route('/<name>/', methods=['GET'])
```

Now, this does not give you the validation. You can either do this yourself, or use a library such as Marshmallow: https://marshmallow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

In your example Marshmallow would be overkill, but it is great if you plan on expanding your API. It will allow you to take more complicated JSON blobs and validate and serialize them into Python objects.

Also, I'd look into why you're using GET over POST. POST should be used to create new data on a server, GET should be used to get that information.

EDIT (After your edits):

> With Flask I cloud do this:
>
> http://127.0.0.1/query/8.8.8.8 
>   But what, if I would use more than one
>   parameter? In PHP it would look like this:

You would make your Flask view like this:

```
@app.route('/<name>/<another_parameter>/<another>/', methods=['GET'])
def some_route_name(name, another_parameter, another):
```

However, if you want to accomplish what you want with ONE form, you would have to turn CSRF off. Your PHP example is not using CSRF.

I suggest this:

1) Creating a new view, as I originally suggested
2) On your view with the form, have it POST to itself, then redirect to the new view, like the below:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    return redirect(url_for('name_of_new_view', name=form.name.data))
```

3) In this new view, put your form, but have that form POST to your OLD view. Make sure you're including the CSRF token when you POST! Like here:

```
{{ form.csrf_token }}
```

Comment: Thank you, for your fast answer Ryan! I'm an absolute beginner and my English is “broken”. I've edited my question again and added a simple PHP-example and an example-link. Perhaps there is nothing like this in Python/ Flask.

Comment: I've added to my answer. I would still suggest using two views! Just do a redirect to the bookmarkable page. This really is the cleanest way, in my opinion!

Comment: Yes, you are right! Redirecting will do the trick. I thought there was an easier way to do this (like in PHP), but doing it this way, I have more work, but also much more control on how the URL is looking like. Thanks a lot Ryan!

Comment: Yes, I'd say try to keep things as separate as you can! It is general good practice to not repeat yourself, but ensure your functions (and views) are doing one thing. :)